# How to store an object in private conversation data with bot framework - state management

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I'm trying to store some data in dialog's so that the value can be used across multiple dialog's to validate and control the flow. I have Root Dialog which forwards the message to Luis Dialog - where I set the value in context.PrivateConversation *this works as long the stored data is of type string or int*. However, I want to store an object - when I try to do that - during the get I always get the default values for the object properties than the values which were originally set. The class for the object instance is a Serializable class under a different namespace in the same project though.

Luis Dialog - Set Data - When I set the data here, the object response have values for most of the properties.

```
public async Task Help(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
 IList<EntityRecommendation> entities = Utility.GetSorttedEntity(result.Entities);
            HelpContext response = getresponse(entities[0].Type, entities);
            string message = response.Responsemessage;
            HelpContext cx = null;
            if (!context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<HelpContext>("HC", out cx))
            {
                context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<HelpContext>("HC", response);
            }
            await this.ShowLuisResult(context, message);
        }
```

Root Dialog - Get Data
Here all the properties for helpcontext is null and false for iserror.

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    HelpContext helpContext = null;
    if (!context.PrivateConversationData.TryGetValue<HelpContext>("HC", out helpContext))
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        await context.Forward(new BasicLuisDialog(), ResumeAfterLuisDialog, activity, CancellationToken.None);
    }
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

HelpContext Class

```
[Serializable]
    public class HelpContext
    {
        internal string Product { get; set; }
        internal string Errorcode { get; set; }
        internal string Action { get; set; }
        internal bool Iserror { get; set; }
        internal string Responsemessage { get; set; }
    }
```

So - I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Or is that - I cannot use object to store private conversation data?

Thanks!

Comment: Good, you've found a solution, you may mark your answer.

Answer (score 3):

After the initial experiment with string values, I started testing with using Dictionary - that was also working, which I was expecting it to fail.That kind of threw me off guard and also made me realize that there is something else basic I'm missing. Again I went back to HelpContext class to look at what I might have missed - apparently problem is with the access modifiers - when I changed the HelpContext properties from "internal" to "public", everything started working the way I was expecting it to. Didn't catch it earlier since the values were accessible during debugging.

Old Code:

```
[Serializable]
    public class HelpContext
    {
        internal string Product { get; set; }
        internal string Errorcode { get; set; }
        internal string Action { get; set; }
        internal bool Iserror { get; set; }
        internal string Responsemessage { get; set; }
    }
```

New Code:

```
[Serializable]
    public class HelpContext
    {
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Errorcode { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }
        public bool Iserror { get; set; }
        public string Responsemessage { get; set; }
    }
```